# Updating dataframe A with values from B

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have df1 with ZIP codes in it (2000 entries, 400 unique zips). I have another df with city and county based upon the zip code (400 entries).

What I would like to do is update df1 with new columns (e.g. country and city) from looking up the correct data in df2.

I have tried a few variations of merge and append, the best I have is a new df with 2400 entries!

pd.merge errors with 'key' problem

p.s. new to this, so please be kind..

```
df1=
ID  Age Experience  Income  ZIPCode     
1   25          1   49      91107
2   35          2   10      90005
[etc....]


df2 =
Zip      city   county  state               
90005   Los Angeles Los Angeles County  CA
[etc....]
```

want :
df[merge]

```
ID  Age Experience  Income  ZIPCode city    county  state   
2   35          2   10      90005  Los Angeles  Los Angeles County  CA
[etc...]
```

Comment: Can't say much without you providing a small snippet what your dataframes look like, but something like `df1.merge(df2, how = 'left', left_on = 'df1_col', right_on = 'df2_col')` ,where `df1_col` and `df2_col` refer to the column name where the ZIP is located, should work. If you're still running into errors, please post the error in full.

Comment: df1.merge(df2, how = 'left', left_on = 'ZIPCode', right_on = 'Zip')                                
error: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: The issue you are running into is one of your ZIP columns is stored as an integer while the other is stored as a string. You want those to match, either both strings or both integers. I don't know which is which, but you want something like `df1['ZIPCode'] = df1['ZIPCode'].astype('int')` or `.astype('string')` prior to merge.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much I have been battling for hours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert your `df1['ZIPCode']` to `str`

```
df1['ZIPCode'] = df1['ZIPCode'].astype(str)
```

then try:

```
df1.merge(df2, how = 'left', left_on = 'ZIPCode', right_on = 'Zip')
```

Comment: converting column type to be the same in two dataframes worked for me - thank you.

Comment: you're welcome..

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a nested loop

```
#df1 [Id, Age, Exp, Income, ZIP]

df1 = [[1, 25, 1, 49, 91107], [2, 35, 2, 10, 90005]]

#df2 [zip, city, county, state]

df2 = [[90005, 'Los Angesles', 'Los Angesles', 'County Ca'], [91107, 'Cape Town', 'Cape town', 'Western Cape']]

#prep holders
final_df = []

for line_df1 in df1:
    for line_df2 in df2:
        if line_df1[4] == line_df2[0]:
            inner_df = [line_df1[0], line_df1[1], line_df1[2], line_df1[3], line_df1[4], line_df2[1], line_df2[2], line_df2[3]]
            final_df.append(inner_df)

for line in final_df:
    print(line)
print(final_df)
```

Comment: IndexError: string index out of range (I changed the index locations to be 'correct' for my df). I think the string might be the problem with this approach? But works perfectly on the data you provided if I modify the df to have- reflect my scenario.

Comment: IndexError indicats that you are retriving an entry that does not exisst, ensure that your data has an entry in all columns, run a loop and check the lenth of each entry, if they are not all the same then that could be your problem